# PhpStorm Twig/JSON autocomplete

Tags: json, autocomplete, twig, phpstorm

I read tons of article, and search on google but nothing...
(some people say the PhpStorm's Twig and JSON support is very bad now...)

I need to work with `.twig` and `.json` files. (PatternLab)

I write Twig code like this: (`search_field.twig`)

```
<div class="molecule--button__search-field">
  <div class="molecule--button__search-field--inner">
    <div class="molecule--button__search-field--inner__input-field {% if car_icon %}car-icon{% endif %}">
      {% if car_icon %}
        <img src="/{{ theme_directory }}/images/icons/ikona_auto.png" alt="car-icon">
      {% endif %}
      <span class="search-input-field-placeholder">{{ search_placeholder_text }}</span>
      <input type="text" class="search-input-field">
    </div>
    <div class="molecule--button__search-field--inner__button">
      <a href="#">{{ search_button_text }}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% if advanced_search_button %}
    {{ include("molecules-advanced-search-button") }}
    <div class="molecule--button__search-field--advanced">
      hello advanced search
    </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

and use variables from `.json` file like: (`search_field.json`)

```
{
  "tag_title": false,
  "tag_s": "Test",
  "category_s": "Nové auto",
  "search_header_background": "style=\"background-image: url(/images/backgrounds/search-background.jpg)\"",
  "search_placeholder_text": "Hledáte radu? Zadejte, co vás zajímá...",
  "search_button_text": "hledej",
  "car_icon": true,
}
```

Is there any plugin or settings option to use autocomplete in Twig files from JSON variable?

Now, when I want to use JSON variable, I need to write down the whole variable name... But I don't want to write down all character so I'm trying to use autocomplete but it's not working yet. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: AFAIK -- none. You may try Symfony plugin though (as it provides extra Twig support) .. but I have no idea if it will even work with non-Symfony code. BTW -- it's not obvious at all why Twig (I mean, IDE in `.twig` files) should complete variables from some `.json` file. As an option -- sure, why not. but as a "must have" feature -- not obvious.

Comment: On related note: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7093 and related tickets

Comment: Hmm, the PhpStorm 2017.1 help say that:
"Based on a schema, PhpStorm checks the structure of .json configuration files, reports errors (for example, informs you about missing mandatory properties), provides code completion and documentation look-up."

[PhpStorm help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/json-schema.html)

Comment: 1) Yeah -- "[JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/)" (separate thing -- something like "XML Schema", generally speaking) -- do you use them? 2) It's for JSON files AFAIK (well, maybe for JS as well) -- so far I do not see relation to Twig here.

Comment: I post an issue on JetBrains PhpStorm youtrack:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36084